# C# Error 'No overload for method 'getData' takes '1' arguments

Tags: c#

I am getting the following error:

```
Error 49 No overload for method 'getData' takes '1' arguments
```

With this method on the 5th line.

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string getVerzekerde(int bsn)
    {
        ZDFKoppeling koppeling = new ZDFKoppeling();
        return koppeling.getData(bsn);             
    }
```

The getData method looks like this:

```
    public string getData(int bsn)
    {         
        using (new SessionScope())
        {
            ZorgVerzekerde verzekerde = PolisModule.GetVerzekerde(bsn);
            return "Verzekerde " + verzekerde.Naam;          
        }     
    }
```

I realy don't understand what is going wrong here.. The description of this error on the msdn site didn't help me.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9s6x486%28VS.80%29.aspx

Someone who has a solution?

Comment: ZDFKoppeling : this is an internal class, right? How are we supposed to know how it is dfined?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yeah; somehow you're compiling against a different version of that class. Do a clean build, and double check your references.

Comment: @Rick, Don't 99% of the time the problem is in our code, so when it is not we tend not to try the obvious

Comment: @Ian - My personal opinion is that if you have to do a clean build in order to get things working then it is a failure of the tool.  Unfortunately I have had a lot of experience recently with having to do so in VS2008 and WPF

Answer (score 1):

Put an error in the GetData() method, then do a full build and confirm that the compiler find the errors.   You may be editing the wrong file if you have more then one copy of the source code on your machine, and this will show you if you are.

Also try renaming the ZDFKoppeling class without updating getVerzekerde() and check you get a compiler error.  If not you are not picking up the changed class for some reason.

If the above does not give a compiler error, try a rebook, as a process my have the dll locked, and also try a complete rebuild.

These problems normally turn out to be very simple once you have tracked them down.  But get take forever to track down.

**If another programmer works in the same office, ask for his/her help, as often a 2nd set of eye on the machine can find it quickly.**

(I am assuming that GetData() is defined in the ZDFKoppeling class, not some other calss)

Answer (score 1):

This generally indicates that it's not referencing the method you thought it was, but instead a different one. You can generally find out what method that is in Visual Studio by right clicking the method call and selecting "Go to definition". This should help work out why it's calling the one it is and not the one you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the `getData` method defined?  Is it in another assembly?  Have you tried rebuilding?

It doesn't look like anything's wrong with your the code.